# Does a Turk need a transit visa for USA when laying over in New York en route to Canada?

Tags: usa, transit-visas, turkish-citizens

I am citizen of Turkey with a Tourist visa for Canada. My flight is from İstanbul through New York then Toronto.

Do I need a US visa for my transit journey?

By the way, we are not ESTA member.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, you need a visa. The United States does not recognize the idea of visa-free transit, you will have to go through Immigration and then go out again.

http://canberra.usembassy.gov/transit-visa.html

The US has a [C-1 Transit Visa](http://turkey.usembassy.gov/transit_visa_c.html) that's supposed to be used for cases like yours, but this is apparently just as is difficult, time-consuming and expensive to get as a regular visa.

Is there any way you can change your flight not to go through the US?  There are plenty of direct flights from Canada to Europe.